# How to enable wireless when booting from a CD?

Tags: wireless

So, I have finally gotten Ubuntu to dual boot on my laptop (yet only from a CD, which is fine with me right now) but the wireless does not work. Before I actually install this, I need to know that wireless and java applications work. Like RuneScape for example. I don't want to install a new OS on my main computer that I use if it cannot run RuneScape or even simple YouTube. When I try to connect to wireless, I'm missing firmware. Where do I get this firmware?

Answer (score 1):

Its probably a closed source driver that will need to be enabled to work.  When you boot up, there (if it is) will be a little pci card icon at the top that will let you know that it needs to enable the driver.  Without the model of your wireless card tho, there is no way to be sure.

Runescape works, in fact, I cant that of a flash game my child hasnt been able to play... or me for that matter.  You tube works.  Your only /real/ concern would be installed games.

Comment: I appreciate it man. I think I figured it out. It does tell me I need to update a drive, which I do. But since it boots from a disk, it doesn't actually change anything as it is only the base operating system.

Comment: Yup.  Ran into that with a friends laptop.  You enable it, it says it needs to 'reboot' then all that work is gone.